# Is it possible to store the recent profiles that I viewed on Facebook on My own android app?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to store the profiles of Facebook users that **I have visited**(name, picture, id, etc.) on another Android app that I want to develop. Is it possible to create this feature? Is it possible to save **my profile visits activity** on Facebook **on another app**?

Comment: No that is not possible.

Comment: That's the simple answer . Thanks.